# How can I show my backend errors via the UI with React

Tags: reactjs, json, react-hooks

This is my function

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState([])
const submitFormAdd = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/invoice`, {
      method: 'put',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-business-name': 'billings',
        "Accept": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        invoiceno: invoiceno,
        description: "facture",
        taxrate: parseInt(taxRate),
        issuedate: invoicedate + "T00:00:00.000Z",
        duedate: invoiceduedate + "T00:00:00.000Z",
        note: "facture",
        taxamount: calcTaxTotal(),
        subtotal: calcLineItemsTotal(),
        total: calcGrandTotal(),
        itemId: 1,
        updatedAt: "2021-07-05T23:00:00.000Z",
        updatedBy: 14,
        createdAt: "2021-07-14T23:00:00.000Z",
        createdBy: 25,
        items: lineItems
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(item => {
      if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        LineItems.props.addItemToState(item[0])
        LineItems.props.toggle()
      }
    })
    //.catch(err => setErrors(err.response.message))
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.response) {
        setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
      }
    })

}
```

I just want to be able to display the backend error in a popup when I submit this invoice. As an example if use an already used invoiceno I get this error in the backend.

```json
{
  "error": {
    "response": {
      "message": "Input data validation failed",
      "_errors": {
        "invoice": "invoice number must be unique."
      }
    },
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Input data validation failed"
  },
  "message": "Error saving invoice"
}
```

I want to be able to display this error in a popup "invoice number must be unique." How can I do that?

I tried to do like this but it's not working.

```
{Object.entries(errors).length > 0 &&
    Object.entries(errors).map(([key, value]) => {
      return <div key={value[0]}>{value[0]}</div>;
    })
}

<div>{errors}</div>
<button className={styles.payNow} onClick={submitFormAdd}>Save Invoice</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? Is there a type error? Does it just not render? What is `errors`? Where does `errors` come from?

Comment: I don't see where you're calling `setErrors`, so `errors` is always going to be an empty array.

Comment: what i meant is i just wanted a popup that shows me the error (as in the backend error i meant)

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterating over the object of errors, which seems to be in `errors.error.response._errors` like the following:

```
<div>
  {Object.entries(errors).length > 0 &&
    Object.entries(errors.error.response._errors).map(([key, value]) => {
      return <div key={key}>{key}: {value}</div>
    })
  }
</div>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t1cybx?file=src/App.js) in action.

Keep in mind `Object.entries(undefined)` will cause an error so you may need to check that `errors` isn't falsy first `errors && Object.entries(errors).length &&`.

Also your default value for useState is wrong. You are providing an array but are you expecting an object. Change the result value to empty object like useState({})

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: this is still not working i think i have a problem with  .catch(error => {
      if (error.response) {
        setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
      }
    })

Comment: Can you console log the error response data errors in the catch? Exactly how it comes in and update your question